# Do I need a SWIG typemap to have a c function return a float to python?

Tags: python, c, numpy, swig

I'm trying to call a C function from python. This function takes a number of arrays as input and returns a float.

Do I need a SWIG typemap to do this? One concern is that python doesn't make a distinction between `floats`, `double`, etc and I'm specifically interested in returning only c-type `float`.

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] illustrating the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning `float` "just works".  You don't need additional typemaps:

**test.i**

```
%module test

%inline %{
    float func(void) { return 1.5; }
%}
```

After running swig and compiling the result:

```
>>> import test
>>> test.func()
1.5
```